# Difference between xib and without xib

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib

I have been developing iPhone Application. But I have a query regarding it that I mainly is to make my application without .xib, I is to create a view while run time, But I wonder I have seen many example on various site where they use xib for making view. Can anyone suggest me which one is the best using xib or without xib.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767512/good-reasons-why-to-not-use-xib-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See using XIB files is good for beginners who do not have much experience in coding but for those developers who have it is for the better that you use coding itself as the XIB files simply increase the load on the program which tends to run slowly than the one without the xib files.... Also Xib files are mainly for the designing process to be smoother you see . Quick development is done through the xib files..